# Getting 'TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars' when storing RGB values in empty array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, string, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe in Pandas as follows where col2 represents rgb values

```
    col1    col2
0   abc     0, 153, 0
1   def     0, 153, 0
2   ghi     0, 102, 255
3   jkl     255, 0, 0
```

Repro:

```
data = {'col1':  ['abc', 'def','ghi','jkl'],
        'col2': ['0, 153, 0', '0, 153, 0', '0, 102, 255','255, 0, 0']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['col1','col2'])
```

I'd like to call upon the distinct color values later, so I then attempt to store them as follows:

```
colors = []
colors.append(float(data.colour.unique()))
```

However this gives the error:

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

If I print the statement I get:

```
print((data.col2.unique()))
['0, 153, 0' '0, 102, 255' '255, 0, 0']
```

But to avoid the error I think I really need the following output:

```
[(0, 153, 0), (0, 102, 255), (255, 0, 0)]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do `str.split`

```
l = df.col2.str.split(', ').map(tuple).unique()
Out[17]: 
array([('0', '153', '0'), ('0', '102', '255'), ('255', '0', '0')],
      dtype=object)
```